# QT IDE and SDK won't install on Mac OS X

Tags: qt, ide, installation, qt-creator

Not sure if this is SO appropriate so feel free to move. It is an IDE though. :)

I want to try the QT IDE on my Snow Leopard machine but for some reason it's not wanting to install. It freezes even (the installer I mean).

I am downloading the 442 meg file from this page: http://qt.nokia.com/downloads

Anyone know why I can't get this to install? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't install that on Snow Leopard.  Try downloading the 4.6 RC and installing that.  You can get the RC [here](http://qt.nokia.com/developer/qt-4.6-preview).

Comment: Will that would explain it. Thanks!

Comment: Installing XCode was all it took. Installed MinGW on windows and it's working there as well.

Answer (score 0):

More Update;

I have success to install Nokia Qt on my MBP - run pretty good. You can get it here

http://www.forum.nokia.com/Develop/Qt/

Only Simulator is allow, No news on Device deployment support yet.